# Max flow with conditional edges

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, max-flow

Is anyone aware of a max flow algorithm where the edges are conditioned upon one another?

Meaning if I send *f* units of flow from vertex *a* --> *b*, then I have to send .5*f* unit from *a* --> *c*.

Comment: You could express maxflow problem as a linear programming problem. You could add constraints of the form you mentioned to the linear program and then solve it via a general purpose LP solver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you describe is a generalization of the *equal flow* problem first proposed by Sahni.  In addition to the flow network, the input specifies several disjoint sets $R_1, R_2, \dots, R_k$ of arcs; the goal is to find a maximum flow such that for each $i$, all arcs in $R_i$ have the same flow value.

While the fractional version of the equal flow problem can be solved in polynomial time by linear programming, the integer version is NP-hard, even if the capacity of each arc is $1$ and all arcs in each set $R_i$ leave the same vertex $v_i$.  Worse, Meyers and Schulz recently proved that there is no polynomial-time $2^{n(1-\epsilon)}$-approximation algorithm, for any fixed $\epsilon>0$, unless $P=NP$.  (The integrality gap of the fractional LP can be arbitrarily large.)

- Carol Meyers and Andreas Schulz.  [Integer equal flows.](http://web.mit.edu/schulz/www/epapers/ms-orl-2009.pdf)  *Operations Research Letters* 37(4):245-249, 2009.